# Using Index to output company of matching MAC addresses, based on first few characters

Tags: excel, csv, indexing, match, vlookup

I am trying to find a way to using index or VLOOKUP to point mac addresses to a world company, based on the first 3 digits. I have a list of mac addresses and then I am pulling a list of worldwide ones. and I am trying to correlate my mac addresses to the corporation its pointing to. I am including what I have so far.

```
0-3D-D1-9E-AB-58    cisco   00-3B-ED-C6-A7-61   cisco
00-3E-FC-C0-7D-D9   dell    00-32-6F-B5-49-7D   dell
00-3A-52-BA-7D-D7   cisco   00-3D-D1-9E-AB-58   cisco
00-36-75-E7-62-F6   dell    00-3B-D3-EC-0B-5E   cisco
00-3D-4B-6A-7E-80   cisco   00-3E-FC-C0-7D-D9   dell
00-38-9B-8A-FD-F1   dell    00-3A-52-BA-7D-D7   cisco
00-3B-ED-C6-A7-61   cisco   00-36-75-E7-62-F6   dell
00-35-CF-0B-C7-70   dell    00-35-CF-0B-C7-70   dell
00-3B-D3-EC-0B-5E   cisco   00-38-9B-8A-FD-F1   dell
00-32-6F-B5-49-7D   dell    00-3D-4B-6A-7E-80   cisco
```

I am using this formula: =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0))

This currently tells me that if the Value in column C matches any value in Column A, then output corresponding value from Column B.

THESE ARE ALL TEST MAC ADDRESSES, but I have a HUGE LIST of them that all have different values minus the first 2 or 3 numbers. I am trying match based off of whatever number of characters I would like, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use a string function.
To search on just the last six(6) characters, for example, something like:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(RIGHT(C1,6),RIGHT(A:A,6),0))
```

You could put the number of characters in some cell and use a cell reference in the formula. You could equally well use `LEFT` or `MID` to match other portions of the MAC address.